# How can I find the index of the maximum value in a matrix column in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, max

I'm trying to find the maximum value of a certain column in a matrix. I want to find both the maximum value and the index of the row in which it is. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15):

`max` command can find both the maximal value and its index.
Here's an example:

```
>> A = randn(10,3)
A = 
       0.8884     -0.10224     -0.86365
      -1.1471     -0.24145     0.077359
      -1.0689      0.31921      -1.2141
      -0.8095      0.31286      -1.1135
      -2.9443     -0.86488   -0.0068493
       1.4384    -0.030051       1.5326
      0.32519     -0.16488     -0.76967
     -0.75493      0.62771      0.37138
       1.3703       1.0933     -0.22558
      -1.7115       1.1093       1.1174

>> [maxVal maxInd] = max(A)
maxVal =
       1.4384       1.1093       1.5326
maxInd =
     6    10     6
```

Comment: Notice, if there are several max values in a column, maxInd will contain only the first occurrence.

Comment: I try that but keep getting the following error: 'Indexing cannot yield multiple results.'

Comment: also, is i know the specific column the max is, I just need it to give me the row, is there a way for that?

Comment: gave me this: [Y,I] = MAX(X)

I tried that and keep getting the same error

Comment: You need this: `[Y,I] = MAX(X,[],DIM)`. If 3rd parameter is 2, you will get max for each row.

Comment: Edit your question to show a sample of your data and the code you use when you get the error.

Comment: @Jonathan: it sounds like a variable in your workspace named "max" is masking the "max" function. They share a namespace in Matlab. Do "which max" to confirm this, and if it's the case, "clear" your workspace to fix it. Organizing your code in functions can help prevent this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the maximum of a specific column, you only pass that column to `max`, or you select the column from the resulting list of indices.

```
%# create an array
A = magic(4)

A =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

%# select the maximum of column 3
[maxValue, rowIdx] = max(A(:,3),[],1)

maxValue =
    15
rowIdx =
     4
```

If you need to look up a corresponding value in another array, you use `otherArray(rowIdx,3)`