# Get the min row of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like:

```
1.0000   24.6914
2.0000   34.5679
3.0000   27.1605
4.0000   30.8642
5.0000   27.1605
6.0000   25.9259
7.0000   14.6914
8.0000   23.4568
9.0000   25.9259
10.0000  22.2222
 ...       ...
23.0000  23.4568
```

I know that if I use

```
min( MATRIX(:,2) )
```

I get the min value of column 2, but how can I get the min value **and** the corresponding value from the first column? From the example, my desired result would be:

```
7.0000   14.6914
```

Comment: Duplicate/Related questions: [How do I get the index of the smallest element in an array in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730244/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-smallest-element-in-an-array-in-matlab), [How can I find the index of the maximum value in a matrix column in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673804/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-matrix-column-in-matlab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to get the index to the min value:

```
[minVal, minInd] = min( MATRIX(:,2) );
```

And then access the 1st row at that index:

```
MATRIX(minInd,1);
```

A little less elegant syntax would be:

```
MATRIX(find(MATRIX(:,2)==min(MATRIX(:,2)),1));
```

Comment: In the last statement, the `find` is unnecessary.

Comment: I know, logical indexing is preferred when possible, just thought the `find` would make it easier to understand. But thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

```
MATRIX(MATRIX(:,2)==min(MATRIX(:,2)),:)
```